# How to back up sql server 2014 db data via bat file?

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, sql-server-2014, database-backups

I am using this query in bat file to back-up db,

```
sqlcmd -S .\MSSQLSERVER -E -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDb @backupLocation='D:\SQLBackups\', @databaseName='TestDb', @backupType='F'" pause
```

It is throwing this error,

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server
>   Network Inte rfaces: Connection string is not valid [87].  Sqlcmd:
>   Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout
>   expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A
>   network-related or in stance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server . Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see  SQL
>   Server Books Online..

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the instance name from the server name specification: `-S .` instead of `-S .\MSSQLSERVER`.

Comment: Does sqlcmd -S .\MSSQLSERVER -E -Q "select 1" return an error?l

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SQLCMD` in a .bat file to make this bakcup, in this link you have an example [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880487/sql-server-command-line-backup-statement)

**SQLCMD**:

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter Transact-SQL statements, system procedures, and script files at the command prompt, in Query Editor in SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file or in an operating system (Cmd.exe) job step of a SQL Server Agent job. This utility uses OLE DB to execute Transact-SQL batches.

here is the link for examples and definition: [msdn link definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.100).aspx)

for example:

```
sqlcmd -E -S %SERVERNAME% -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK = N'%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'%DATABASENAME% backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
```

hope this help!