# SQL backup job script windows schedule task

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, backup-sqldatabase

I knew about the possibility to get backup db using SQL server agent, but I was curious to know if we can have a backup script (like batch file) that just runs in windows and gets automatic backup according to the schedule that we define?

I think for the next part we can use windows task schedule (or crontab) for run the backup script job routinely, but the most important thing is to know: is it possible to login via SQL and backup the DB just using a batch scrip file (that there not be any need for SQL management studio completely and work completely independent)?
If the answer is yes, please let me know that I have it, too.

Maybe it seems to be a silly question, but I am not so experienced about that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!.

If you have SQLServer Express version you can't use SQLAgent, so the only way is outside of the SQLServer, like a .bat file. In this link you have an example script. [.Bat Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880487/sql-server-command-line-backup-statement)

now you can use schedule task to schedule the backup.

If you can use SQL Agent, you could create a Mainteinance Plan for a Full Backup and next create a Job in SQL Agent to run it. In this link is you can find some examples, with script and mainteinance Plan and Jobs: [With SQLAgent](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-create-a-sql-server-scheduled-backup/)

hope this help!

Comment: Dear Mauro, You exactly mentioned what I want. so grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not Express, you create a backup job, which you can do in SQL Server Management Studio, and then schedule that backup job: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017#SSMS
and
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-create-a-sql-server-scheduled-backup/
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdKePm7ImkM

Also maybe buy the SQL Server DBA exam guide and work through it, they go over it in fine detail.
Hope that helps.