# How to automatically backup TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, backup

I'm evaluating Team Foundation Server 2010.

I would like to know if there is some command line to backup my TFS data.
I currently have a folder sent to the cloud. This backup contains all the data I need to back up (like MySql databases, word documents, ...)

What I want is a way to automatically backup my TFS collections (and any other important TFS data) in one (or more) file in this directory.

A command line would be perfect.

Comment: you mean like a standard SQL SErver backup?

Comment: I'm not a user of SQL Server. In fact I plan to use it for TFS but never really played with it.

I think that there is more than just backup the SQL database for a TFS backup.

I'm currently using Subversion and the backup procedure is very easy. I looked at the MSDN documentation for backing up TFS but didn't find any command line that I can launch via the task scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TFS documentation [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/back-up-restore?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) covers this.

If you are using full SQL Server you can use SQL Server Agent to schedule database backups, otherwise use Windows task scheduler (via one of the SQL command line tools). But you do need to write the SQL script to do the backing up, this is explained in some detail in the documentation linked above.

(There is no simple command line because simple installations have different needs to complex ones, e.g. on a large instance backups can take many hours and issues of synchronisation of the backups becomes complex.)

Additional [edit 2010-08-24] the next TFS PowerToys have been announced to include backup and recovery tools (targeted for non-large scale TFS setups). See the blog post: "[Backing up and Restoring your TFS Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/backing-up-and-restoring-your-tfs-server/)"

Comment: you can use command line to run a backup...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122690/what-is-a-simple-command-line-program-or-script-to-backup-sql-server-databases

Answer (score 0):

This might be of help to you as it explains a full detailed Backup with many different methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx